# replace fossil-fuel kit on dual-fuel heat pump with upgraded thermostat

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I have a 25-year old dual-fuel heat pump (about which I've asked many questions here).  There is a PCB in the furnace/air-handler called a "fossil-fuel kit" that handles switching between the heat pump and propane, depending upon the outside temperature, the delta between inside temperature and indoor set-point of the thermostat, and an explicit call for emergency/auxiliary heat.

The fossil-fuel board appears to be failing.  I want to replace my thermostat with one which is dual-fuel capable, and eliminate the fossil-fuel board.  This will solve the problem, and makes sense as an upgrade, giving more control over the heating. I have acquired a Nest Thermostat E.   I'm not sure how to wire it properly.

The Nest thermostat has 6 terminals: R, C, G, Y1, *O/B, W1.    Am I correct that these operate as follows ?   I plan to bench test the thing to confirm:

- R and C: 24vac power
- G: energized to turn on air-handler fan
- Y1: energized to turn on compressor
- *O/B: energized to switch heat pump to "cooling" mode
- W1: energized to turn-on auxiliary/emergency heat

The furnace/air-handler control board has inputs R, C, G, Y, W.

Wires leading to/from the outdoor unit (compressor) are R, C, O, Y, W.

Should I simply connect all the wires of same (or similar, e.g. Y and Y1) color designation together ?

A few things confuse me about this.   First, why does the furnace/air-handler need the Y signal ?  The G will turn the fan on when the compressor is running.  Perhaps it's just there for convenience, in forwarding the Y1 signal from the thermostat to the compressor ?

I'm quite confused about the W and W1 signals.  Am I correct that the W signal from the compressor is an output, that it's basically the compressor saying "I'm in defrost mode, you need to turn on auxiliary heat if required" ?  But the W1 signal from the thermostat also says "turn on auxliiary/emergency heat".  Is the W input to the furnace/air-handler thus a sort of wired-OR input, it turns on the furnace if either W1 from the thermostat, or W from the compressor, is energized ? But if the thermostat is not calling for heat at all, there's no reason the compressor defrost should start the furnace.  So it seems like the logic to turn on the furnace should be W(furnace) = W1 + W(compressor) * Y * Obar ("turn on the furnace if the thermostat is calling for auxiliary heat, or the thermostat is calling for heat-pump heat and the compressor is in defrost mode").  That would explain why the furnace/air-handler needs the Y input, and I suppose it doesn't need the O input since the compressor never goes into defrost mode if O is energized and it's in cooling mode.

The following photographs may be helpful.   They show how the system was previously connected (using the fossil-fuel kit).  (Comments on each photo are ABOVE the photo).

The connections to the fossil-fuel PCB.   Thermostat connections at the bottom, daisy-chained over to connections on the furnace/air-handler's control board. Add'l connections to the furnace (the big black wires on the left-hand side).  Connections to the compressor at the top.  Connections to some sort of sensors by the indoor coil by the two brown-jacketed cables; I'll delete these, nothing to hook 'em to.

[image: connections to the fossil-fuel PCB]

Schematic of the furnace/air-handler.  It appears to show no connections to the Y and G terminals.   But it must connect to the G, to energize the air-handler.

[image]

The schematic of the fossil-fuel board.  It looks like B is synonymous with C (on the connections to the compressor).  Note the W connection from the compressor does not go straight to the furnace, so the fossil-fuel board probably implements something like the logic I suggest.  So without the fossil-fuel board, how do I make this operate sensibly ?

[image]

Comment: Many of you are probably saying "maybe Rusty ought to be thinking about replacing this system".   And Rusty thinks you are probably right.   I'm thinking to put in a couple of mini-split heat pumps.   One in the large living/dining/kitchen area that is half the house's square-footage.   One in the master bedroom, which is most of the rest.   And then maybe run the old air-handler to distribute heat (e.g. to the guest bedroom) if required.

Comment: I love the simplicity of the mini-split - none of this hassling with auxiliary heat.  it never gets below zero here, almost never in single digits, and rarely in the teens.